# unable to login to pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

after installing binary version (10.11.3) of postgressql, i set the username and password and username and started pgAdmin4. it was asking password to login but whenever i give correct password, it was giving incorrect password. So i reset MASTER_PASSWORD= false in

postgresql-10.11-3-windows-x64-binaries\pgsql\pgAdmin 4\web\congig.py file. I restarted the server. i am getting the below screen and i am unable to login.

I am not sure what is the problem.

[image]

Comment: You should not alter the config.py file.  See here: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/4.17/config_py.html . Aren't you having problems logging into the postgresql server itself?  This config is for the web interface.  Perhaps verify and modify the question with more accurate error messages.

Comment: i m unable to login to server..

Comment: Are you not able to Add new server for instance - or is everything grayed out?

Comment: can you connect with psql?

Comment: everything greyed out

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at a loss here.  Sorry.